# How to handle all WebSocket errors without a race?

Tags: javascript, websocket

When I run code

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://mydomain.example/socket/service");
ws.addEventListener("error", function (error)
{
  console.error("Got error=", error);
});
```

**Is it possible that the WebSocket connection fails (emit `error`) before I can attach the event listener for the `error` event?**

Looking at the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/WebSocket I cannot see this detail documented anywhere.

According to the [WHATWG spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-sockets.html#dom-websocket) it seems that the constructor should run the request *in parallel* – is there a guarantee that I can attach the error listener before any possible errors can raise?

Comment: `Is it possible that the WebSocket connection fails (emit error) before I can attach the event listener for the error event?` No. The constructor might throw though.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Probably somewhere in the documentation of the JavaScript event loop. This is not specific to websockets, pretty much any eventemitter is required to emit events asynchronously, otherwise half the internet would break.

Comment: I agree that it's the only sane implementation. I'm asking for documentation or spec because WHATWG spec says about *in parallel*: "To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run, one after another, at the same time as other logic in the standard (e.g., at the same time as the event loop). " at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel – if you execute the code "at the same time" parallel to native event loop without syncronization things start to break down. If this is interpreted "handle these tasks as part of event loop processing" it all makes sense.

Comment: I'd prefer to use documented features only, instead of using features that just make sense as a real world implementation but are not documented anywhere.

Comment: `if you execute the code "at the same time" parallel to native event loop without syncronization things start to break down.` Nope. This part of the documentation is talking about IO threads and so on. JavaScript events __can not__ run parallel as the event loop is the only one who is allowed to run JavaScript, and it is single threaded.

Comment: If you check the WHATWG spec link I included in the question, you'll find that the spec literally says about the constructor implementation *"**Run this step in parallel:** Establish a WebSocket connection given urlRecord, protocols, and client."* Obviously, this is implementation detail for the browser engine and it *could* be implemented without usual JavaScript limitations.

Comment: For example, JavaScript execution definitely doesn't stop while the browser is executing asyncronous AJAX query or fetching CSS files. And fetching those CSS files is not syncronized to any JavaScript.

Comment: `For example, JavaScript execution definitely doesn't stop while the browser is executing asyncronous AJAX query` Correct, but the _callbacks_ for those AJAX requests won't run in parallel with your other JavaScript.

Comment: I fully agree that all callbacks are executed syncronized to event loop. I still feel that the WHATWG spec doesn't actually require UA to wait for next event loop event before connecting to WebSocket server because that can be done `in parallel` according to spec. And I think events can be fired so that the listeners are selected at the moment of error which could (in theory?) happen before the above code can attach the listener for event `error`. If the spec said that that the WebSocket connection is started via event loop, I would have nothing to worry here.

Comment: I think this is just a wording issue in the spec and I reported it here: https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebSocket` constructor is run without synchronization of any kind and the connection may indeed encounter an error *before* the line with `ws.addEventListener("error", ...);` is executed! However, this is not a problem because the spec also says that in case of error, the actual `error` event is fired as a part of steps that must be queued as a task. In practice, this means that logically the WebSocket constructor is required to behave as if it would run an anonymous function with zero timeout which fires the `error` event.

So the actual error can happen before the JS code can attach the event listener but all the *events* (`open`, `close`, `error`, `message`) can only be *fired delayed* after the event loop is executed next time so the above code will always have to time attach the event handlers before the events can be fired.

See https://github.com/whatwg/websockets/issues/13#issuecomment-1039442142 for details.